# What do I need to do if I want to use database data conditionally in Django templates?

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-templates

I am working on an ecommerce store in Django. I want to know that how do I use the database data passed to templates using `render()` method, conditionally through JavaScript or AJAX or JSON?

For example, let's say I have a following `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Suit(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'suit-products/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Buttoning(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, verbose_name = "Title")
    img = models.FileField(upload_to = 'buttonings/', null = True, verbose_name = "Picture")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

and following  `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    suit_prods             = Suit.objects.all()
    buttoning = Buttoning.objects.all()

    context {
        "suit_prods": suit_prods,
        "buttoning": buttoning
    }

    return render(request, "index/index.html", context)
```

and following `index.html` (template):

```
    {% for element in suit_prods %}
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <div id="menu">
                    <img src="{{ element.img.url }}" />
                    <span>{{ element.title }}</span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Now what I want is, if the clicked `element` in the list items in `index.html` has the `title` as `"two_piece_suit"` then show items of `{{ buttoning }}` as a list, otherwise pass.

If I explain it more using some JS syntax, then I want following kind of behaviour:

```
<scrip>
    var suit_menu = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
    for(var i = 0; i < suit_menu.length; i++) {
        if(suit_menu.text == "two_piece_suit") {
            {% for element in buttoning %}
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div id="buttoning">
                            <img src="{{ element.img.url }}" />
                            <span>{{ element.title }}</span>
                            <span></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't necessarily need JavaScript to achieve this.  Also, `<script>` is missing a t, and your for loop doesn't seem to add the HTML to the document at all.

You can achieve that purely with the Django Template Language by integrating the buttons for loop with an if condition like this:

```
{% if element.title == 'two_piece_suit' %}
    {% for button in buttoning %}
        <Some HTML>{{ button.title }}</Some HTML>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

That way, the list of buttons is only displayed if the title is two_piece_suit.